# Como executar um JAR com uma JRE especifica?

Tags: java

Tenho o Java 7, 8 e 9 instalado na mesma máquina e quero fazer meu programa rodar usando o Java 7, como que faz isso em? (pode ser em linha de comando ou não).

Comment: Ou na hora de chamar jar usa o caminho completo da JRE ou tente criar variáveis de ambiente para cada uma ...

Answer (score 1):

Ola,

Basta rodar o javaw.exe que fica na pasta do Java 7

Supondo que o seu Java 7 esteja na pasta

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin
```

Se você estiver no windows abra um prompt do DOS e a partir deste caminho você irá executar o seu jar assim

No prompt do DOS

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin
javaw.exe -jar MeuJar.jar
```

Comment: Mas eu tenho que colocar meu .jar na mesma pasta do javaw.exe?? Se eu quiser rodar em diretorios diferentes como que fica??

Comment: Não precisa, você pode criar por exemplo um arquivo .bat e colocar o jar onde quiser, tem duas opções, ou você faz um cd para a pasta ou executa o caminho completo

Comment: suponha que o seu .jar esteja em uma pasta c:/tmp você poderia colocar assim no seu arquivo .bat

Comment: #arquivo.bat
cd c:/tmp
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/bin/javaw.exe MeuJar.jar

Comment: ou assim
#arquivo.bat
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/bin/javaw.exe c:/tmp/MeuJar.jar

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade é alternando o java default. Em um ambiente linux (shell bash) você pode usar os comandos:

```
sudo apt install oracle-java7-set-default
sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
sudo apt install oracle-java9-set-default
```

Para verificar a versão:

```
java -version

>>>
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```